# mysql select query does not return result when where clause condition surrounded by single quotes

Tags: mysql

Created table TestTbl1 (colA varchar(255),colB varchar(255),colC varchar(255),colD varchar(255)).

After that I loaded the table using LOAD DATA INFILE

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\data.csv' INTO TABLE TestTbl1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

Example of data in the file

```
0:618:0:1,AA,2301,51570
0:618:0:2,AA,2301,53332
```

Then in MySQL Workbench I ran this query

```
select * from TestTbl1 where colD='51570'
```

I do not get any result

But, when I run this query I get result

```
select * from TestTbl1 where colD=51570
```

Comment: Just a guess: the single quotes makes MySQL look for strings, rather than integers. Can you replicate the same actions with a char column?

Comment: I changed colD to char(10) and reran the query I do not get any result.

Comment: Any chance that the CSV file was read in with a trailing newline or CRLF hanging on to the last field (the colD)? If so, '51570' might not match because the string is longer than 5 characters. Browse around in phpMyAdmin and/or print out the field and see if there is any evidence of more character(s) after the 5 visible ones.

Comment: Phil there is an extra character.  So how do I make sure that there isn't one when i use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE